# Quilljs - How to get data at server side in ASP.net using QuillJS Text Editor

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, quil

I am implementing Quilljs text editor in ASP.net.

Below is my .aspx file code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>          
    <link href="quill/quill.core.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="quill/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
    <script src="quill/quill.js"></script>
    <script src="quill/quill.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div style="height: 360px; background-color: white; width: 100%" id="txtbQdesc">
      <p>
            <br />
        </p>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var quill = new Quill('#txtbQdesc', {
            modules: {
                toolbar: [['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'], [{ list: 'ordered' }, { list: 'bullet' }],
                  ['link', 'blockquote', 'code-block']
                ]
            },
            placeholder: '...',
            theme: 'snow'  // or 'bubble'
        });</script>

</body>
</html>
```

What I need to do is, I need to get content of `div` at server side. To make this possible, I need to add `runat=server` properties in `div` tag.

But as soon as I add runat properties to `div` tag, toolbar of editor disappears.

Is there something I am missing.

Can anyone please suggest any workaround.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The focus of the tutorial is another, but see if it helps:[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51547074/quill-rich-text-editor-resize-image-only-works-in-ie-but-not-in-chrome-or-edge)

Answer (score 0):

Double check the ID that .NET creates for the div tag. 
You might have the name "txt_EditBody" but .NET will change the name to something like "cph_Body_txt_EditBody".