# Quill rich text editor resize image only works in IE but not in Chrome or Edge

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, text-editor, quill

I implemented Quill text editor to my web app. I created a web app in asp.net core 2.1

Quill text editor resizing an image working fine in IE but not in Chrome or Edge.

Is this already known issue for other browsers? If so, only IE is suitable for resizing an image thru Quill editor?

If you tell me only IE can resize an image thru Quill, I have to use different text editor I guess.. hope not though.. If I have to use different one, can you recommend one that is open source?

Thank you in advance!

Here is how I have done in html:

```html
<!-- Main Quill library -->
<script src="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.min.js"></script>
<!-- Theme included stylesheets -->
<link href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div id="editor-container" style="height:600px"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
        modules: {
            toolbar: [
                [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
                [{ 'font': [] }],
                [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],
                ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike', 'blockquote'],
                [{ 'list': 'ordered' }, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
                [{ 'indent': '-1' }, { 'indent': '+1' }],          // outdent/indent
                [{ 'align': [] }],
                ['image', 'link'],
            ]
        },
        theme: 'snow'  // or 'bubble'
    });
</script>
```

Comment: nice article for image resizing https://blog.almightytricks.com/2020/10/21/ngx-quill-image-resize/

Answer (score 4):

I'm using quill editor with vue and I had to install some modules for image resize:

**1 Install modules**

```
yarn add quill-image-resize-module --save
yarn add quill-image-drop-module --save
```

**or using npm:**

```
npm install quill-image-resize-module --save
npm install quill-image-drop-module --save
```

**2 Import and register modules**

```
import { ImageDrop } from 'quill-image-drop-module'
import ImageResize from 'quill-image-resize-module'
Quill.register('modules/imageDrop', ImageDrop)
Quill.register('modules/imageResize', ImageResize)
```

**3 Add editor options**

```
editorOption: {
    modules: {
        toolbar: [
            ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],        
              ['blockquote'/*, 'code-block'*/],

              [{ 'list': 'ordered'}, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
              [{ 'indent': '-1'}, { 'indent': '+1' }],          

              [{ 'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],  
              [{ 'header': [/*1,*/ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],

              [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],          
              [{ 'font': [] }],
              [{ 'align': [] }],

              ['clean']                                         
        ],

        history: {
            delay: 1000,
            maxStack: 50,
            userOnly: false
        },
        imageDrop: true,
        imageResize: {
          displayStyles: {
            backgroundColor: 'black',
            border: 'none',
            color: 'white'
          },
          modules: [ 'Resize', 'DisplaySize', 'Toolbar' ]
        }
    }
}
```

I hope will help you.

Comment: Where do you write import & register modules?

Comment: M, Can you try in Chrome and see resize image working??

Comment: M, My Chrome can't resize image in the link you gave me: codepen.io/tesis/pen/djddgg My Chrome is the most recent version though.

Comment: Developer tool shows error "quill Cannot import modules/imageResize. Are you sure it was registered?"

Comment: @SeongEKim in code pen is just an example, how to do it. I didn't add a link for image resize, but you have it in your node_modules folder

Comment: Can you make codepen for me? I can't still solve this issue. Thanks!!

Comment: Info is old. Many dependencies are deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

**displaySize: true // default false**

`<script src="quill-image-resize-module-master/image-resize.min.js"></script>`

```
 var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
        theme: 'snow',
         modules: {
            imageResize: {
              displaySize: true // default false
            },
           toolbar: [
             [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
             ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
             [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }], 
             [{ 'align': [] }],
             ['link', 'image'],

             ['clean']  
           ]
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to implement the image resize module *cross-browser* would be to download the ZIP from GitHub:
https://github.com/kensnyder/quill-image-resize-module

Extract the contents in your root folder, then call it from your HTML.

```
<!-- Quill HTML WYSIWYG Editor -->
<!-- Include Quill stylesheet -->
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.0/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Include the Quill library -->
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.0/quill.js"></script>
<!-- Quill Image Resize Module -->
<script src="quill-image-resize-module-master/image-resize.min.js"></script>
```

Next add it to your Quill config:

```
var quillObj = new Quill('#editor-container', {
modules: {
imageResize: {},
toolbar: '#toolbar-container'
},
theme: 'snow'
});
```

[Demo Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/gq708AOrSBOWSlHcFslG?p=preview)